# navigationManager.NavigateTo not work after delete the record

Tags: c#, navigation, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-client-side

navigate.manager not work after delete the record

I am trying to when record is deleted then move on this page(https://localhost:44399/DisplayEmployeeData)

my record is deleted successfully but note navigate and give the error

[image]

**Client Side:**

DeleteEmployee.razor

```
@using CrudBlazorServerApp.Data
@page "/DeleteEmployee/{id}"
@inject HttpClient Http
@using System.Net.Http
@inject NavigationManager navigationManager

<h3>DeleteEmployee</h3>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">

        @if (emp != null)
        {
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="username" class="control-label">username:</label>
                    @emp.username
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="empaddress" class="control-label">empaddress:</label>
                    @emp.empaddress
                </div>
                <div class=" form-group">
                    <label asp-for="password" class="control-label">password:</label>
                    @emp.password
                </div>
                <div class=" form-group">
                    <label asp-for="country" class="control-label">country:</label>
                    @emp.country
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button @onclick="Delete">Delete</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        }
    </div>
</div>

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    Emp emp;
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync() =>
        emp = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<Emp>("https://localhost:44333/api/emps/getemp/" + Id);

    private async Task Delete()
    {
        @if (Id != null)
        {
            
            string url = "https://localhost:44333/api/emps/checkDelete?empid=" + Id;
            await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<Emp>(url);
            navigationManager.NavigateTo("https://localhost:44399/DisplayEmployeeData"); //here I am facing issue not navigate
        }
    }
}
```

**ServerSide(WebApi):**

EmpsController.cs

```
        [HttpGet]
        public Emp checkDelete(int empid, string username, string empaddress, string password, string country)
        {
            var deletercord = _context.emps
                .Where(s => s.empid == empid)
                .FirstOrDefault();
            deletercord.username = username;
            deletercord.empaddress = empaddress;
            deletercord.password = password;
            deletercord.country = country;

            _context.emps.Remove(deletercord);
            _context.SaveChanges();

            return deletercord;
        }
```

I want to when user press the delete then navigate the page

Comment: Your api is returning 404 error so please check that first

Comment: if my api give 404  then why delete the record successfully?

Comment: @Umair please see this image your doubt is clear you said 404 error but console and watch window not give 404 error https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPR8M.png which place give the 404 error?can you give suggestion which place I am doing wrong

Comment: @Umair record is deleted from the database also https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5Jlz.png which place need to correction can you give hint

Comment: @RahulPatil Don't use a HttpGet for a delete.

Comment: As Orak suggested, its good to use `HttpDelete` instead of `HttpGet` and also use `NavigateTo` like this if its in the same application: `navigationManager.NavigateTo("/DisplayEmployeeData");` Also why does your API have username, empaddress, password etc, you don't really need that if you are deleting a record?

Comment: @RahulPatil Why do you update it before you delete it?

Comment: Your page gets a 404 not found error at the line `emp = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<Emp>("https://localhost:44333/api/emps/getemp/" + Id);`  It is not the navigationmanager. Make null check inside your OnInitializedAsync() method with a try-catch block

Comment: @Orak Why do you update it before you delete it? - No now I use the post for delete but give 404 not found error please see this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8TP4.png this api and this method give an error ```protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync() =>
        emp = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<Emp>("https://localhost:44333/api/emps/getemp/" + Id);```

Comment: @Umair I use the httpdelete then give the same error 404 not found see this referance https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyNlE.png I think issue is here ```protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync() =>         emp = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<Emp>("https://localhost:44333/api/emps/getemp/" + Id);``` because OnInitializedAsync first run can you give solution for this?

Comment: Sorry just to clarify, the `HttpDelete` change was a suggestion. you will have to debug your code to see what the error is, try running that API call in tools like Postman, and see if that works?

Comment: @Umair perfectly work httpdelete in postman see this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/asOmU.png issue is this function OnInitializedAsync because this function run first time when page is refresh

Comment: What is the http response in postman?

Comment: @Umair 200 ok and record is deleted from the database see this https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6d05.png still I am trying to find the solution ```[HttpDelete]
 public Emp checkDelete(int empid){ var deletercord = _context.emps
                .Where(s => s.empid == empid)
                .FirstOrDefault();           
                _context.emps.Remove(deletercord);
                _context.SaveChanges();

                  return deletercord;
        }```

Comment: @Umair I want to navigate index page when record is deleted  ```<a href='/EditEmployee/@emp.empid'>Edit</a>
                    <a href='/DeleteEmployee/@emp.empid'>Delete</a>```

Comment: @Umair  when I click on delete link and then call deleteEmployee page and then first run this method  ```OnInitializedAsync```

Comment: So after record is deleted what should happen?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221084/discussion-between-rahul-patil-and-umair).

Comment: @Orak issue is not solved

Comment: Ok I have managed to work on my machine, your project structure needs changing, so let me know in the chat above when you are available. After confirming it works on your machine I can post a solution here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221139/discussion-between-rahul-and-umair).

Answer (score 1):

Your page gets a 404 not found error at the line `emp = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<Emp>("https://localhost:44333/api/emps/getemp/" + Id);`
It is not the navigationManager. Change your OnInitializedAsync() method with a try-catch block into something like this:

```
public override async void OnInitialized()
    {
        try 
        {
            emp = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<Emp>("https://localhost:44333/api/emps/getemp/" + Id);
        }
        catch(Exception exc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Employee deleted ");
emp = new Employee() {Id=0};
        }
}
```

Comment: when I use OnInitialized() then not able to get the delete data see this image  https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UwE3.png when I click edit link then not display any data